# Summary average rounding not working

Tags: angularjs, jqgrid, grouping, summary

I'm using jqGrid with AngularJS to make a small web.
I have created a grid with some data, using jqGrid grouping including a summary row.
I've changed summary row position to the main row of each group.

I want some summary cells that have to be averages rounded to 2 decimals, but I don't get it working.

This is the colModel definition for one of the rows which I want to round:

```
{name:'cost', label:'Total Cost', width:55, summaryType:'avg',summaryRound:2, summaryRoundType:'round'}
```

How can I get that column rounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `formatter:'number'` in the colModel...

Please, take more time to do some research before asking next time.